# fetch reactively in solidjs

Tags: javascript, solid-js

How do I fetch data reactively? I need to insert the Data into graphjs afterwards, with the createResource Hook I only get data that works with the solid For Loop, what am I doing wrong?

ps: pretty new to solid

Answer (score 1):

You can reactively use data from a resource using an effect like this, which is similar to what  does internally:

```js
// `data` starts undefined, then later resolves
const [data] = createResource(...);
createEffect(() => {
  if (data()) {
    // Do something with the data
  }
});
```